# Groups of repeating items

Tags: code-golf, array

## Challenge description

Given a list / array of items, display all groups of consecutive repeating items.

## Input / output description

Your input is a list / array of items (you can assume all of them are of the same type). You don't need to support every type your language has, but is has to support at least one (preferably `int`, but types like `boolean`, although not very interesting, are also fine). Sample outputs:

```
[4, 4, 2, 2, 9, 9] -> [[4, 4], [2, 2], [9, 9]]
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4] -> [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4]]
[1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3] -> [[1, 1, 1], [3, 3], [1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [1, 1], [3]]
[9, 7, 8, 6, 5] -> [[9], [7], [8], [6], [5]]
[5, 5, 5] -> [[5, 5, 5]]
['A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Z'] -> [['A'], ['B', 'B', 'B'], ['C'], ['D'], ['X'], ['Y', 'Y'], ['Z']]
[True, True, True, False, False, True, False, False, True, True, True] -> [[True, True, True], [False, False], [True], [False, False], [True, True, True]]
[0] -> [[0]]
```

As for empty lists, output is undefined - it can be nothing, an empty list, or an exception - whatever suits your golfing purposes the best. You don't have to create a separate list of lists either, so this is a perfectly valid output as well:

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 9] ->

1 1 1
2 2
3 3 3
4
9
```

The important thing is to keep the groups separated in some way. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in bytes wins

Comment: Maybe we output a list that has some special separator value?

Comment: @xnor: Can you provide an example? An array of `int`s separated by, for instance, `0`s  would be a bad idea since there can be `0`s in the input...

Comment: For example, `[4, 4, '', 2, 2, '', 9, 9]` or `[4, 4, [], 2, 2, [], 9, 9]`.

Comment: Actually, what types do we have to support. Can the elements themselves to be lists? I imagine some languages have built-in types that can't be printed or have weird equality-checking.

Comment: @xnor: Yeah, that's what my concern was - if your input has lists inside it, then using empty list as a separator might be confusing. That's why I included "you can assume all the items are of the same type", so that can use a different type as a separator.

Comment: Does our code really have to work for every type that exists in the language? I think this introduces too many corner-case with languages that support objects that change when accessed, that are not equal to themselves, that cannot be printed, etc. It's recommended to stick to [just integers or simplier](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8437/20260) for challenges like these.

Comment: No, of course not. Using only one specified type is fine. I'll include this in the description.

Comment: Oh, I was misunderstanding. So you're saying we get to choose what type of elements our code works for, and it only has to work for that type? I presume using a type that has only a single value is not OK (though you should say so).

Comment: My point is you don't have to go out of your way to support every single edge case if your language of choice is not suitable for such operations. I'd say that supporting one specified type (like `int`) is an absolute minimum for your program to be considered valid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42006/discussion-between-xnor-and-shooqie).

Comment: Is an I/O format like `abbcccddd` → `a bb ccc ddd` acceptable?

Comment: Sure. A lot of languages treat strings as a list/array of chars, which is fine.

Answer (score 15):

### Mathematica, 5 bytes

```
Split
```

... there's a built-in for that.

Comment: …what a surprise!

Comment: @Fatalize The real surprise is how short it is.

Answer (score 9):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
I0;œṗ
```

Works for all numeric types. [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=STA7xZPhuZc&input=&args=WzQsIDQsIDIsIDIsIDksIDld) or [verify all numeric test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=STA7xZPhuZcKw4figqzhuYTigqzhuZvigJw&input=&args=WzQsIDQsIDIsIDIsIDksIDldLCBbMSwgMSwgMSwgMiwgMiwgMywgMywgMywgNCwgNCwgNCwgNF0sIFsxLCAxLCAxLCAzLCAzLCAxLCAxLCAyLCAyLCAyLCAxLCAxLCAzXSwgWzksIDcsIDgsIDYsIDVdLCBbNSwgNSwgNV0sIFsxLCAxLCAxLCAwLCAwLCAxLCAwLCAwLCAxLCAxLCAxXSwgWzBd).

#### How it works

```
I0;œṗ  Main link. Argument: A (array)

I      Increments; compute the differences of consecutive elements.
 0;    Prepend a zero.
   œṗ  Partition; split A at truthy values in the result to the left.
```

Answer (score 8):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>15</s> 8 bytes

*Thanks to Lynn for suggesting a simpler I/O format.*

```
!`(.)\1*
```

Treats the input as a list of characters (and uses linefeeds to separate groups).

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=IWAoXGQrKSggXDFcYikq&input=MSAxIDEgMiAyIDMgMyAzIDQgOQ)

This simply works by matching groups and printing them all (which uses linefeed separation automatically).

Comment: I asked about `abbcccddd` → `a bb ccc ddd` being an acceptable I/O format, and the OP approved of it, so I guess ``!`(.)\1*`` is fine?

Comment: @Lynn Oh, that's indeed much simpler, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 9 bytes

```
Y'v"@Z}Y"

Y'     % Take input. Run-length encoding. Gives two row arrays: values and run lengths
v      % Concatenate vertically   
"      % For each column
  @Z}  %   Push column and split into its two elements
  Y"   %   Run-length decoding
       % End for. Implicitly display
```

Input is a row array of **numbers**, with spaces or commas as separators.

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=WSd2IkBafVki&input=WzEgMSAyIDEgMiAyXQ) Test with [non-integer numbers](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=WSd2IkBafVki&input=WzEuMSAyLjIgMS4xIDEuMSAtMS4xIDIuMl0).

---

## MATL, 11 bytes

```
lidgvYsG7XQ
```

Input is a column array of either **numbers** or **characters**, using `;` as separator.

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=bGlkZ3ZZc0c3WFE&input=WzE7IDE7IDI7IDE7IDI7IDJd) Test with [arbitrary numbers](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=bGlkZ3ZZc0c3WFE&input=WzEuMTsgMi4yOyAxLjE7IDEuMTsgLTEuMTsgMi4yXQ). Test with [characters](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=bGlkZ3ZZc0c3WFE&input=WydhJzsnYic7J2EnOydhJzsnYic7J2MnOydjJzsnYidd).

```
l     % Push 1
i     % Take input, say [4;4;2;2;9;9]
d     % Consecutive differences of input: [0;-2;0;7;0]
g     % Convert to logical: gives 1 if consecutive entries were different: [0;1;0;1;0]
v     % Concatenate vertically with the initial 1: [1;0;1;0;1;0]
Ys    % Cumulative sum. Each value is a group label: [1;1;2;2;3;3]
G     % Push input again
7XQ   % Split into horizontal arrays as indicated by group labels: {[4 4];[2 2];[9 9]}
      % Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>39</s> 37 bytes

```js
f=
s=>s.replace(/(\w+) (?!\1\b)/g,`$1
`)
;
```

```html
<input oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value);><pre id=o>
```

Works on any space-separated word-like tokens. Saved 2 bytes thanks to @MartinEnder♦. Best I could do for array input and return is 68:

```
a=>a.reduce((l,r)=>(l==r?c.push(r):b.push(c=[r]),r),b=[c=[a[0]]])&&b
```

Comment: I added an array answer at 56

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com), 13 bytes

```
<;.1~1,2~:/\]
```

Since J does not support ragged arrays, each run of equal elements is boxed. The input is an array of values and the output is array of boxed arrays.

### Usage

```
   f =: <;.1~1,2~:/\]
   f 4 4 2 2 9 9
┌───┬───┬───┐
│4 4│2 2│9 9│
└───┴───┴───┘
   f 1 1 1 3 3 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 3
┌─────┬───┬───┬─────┬───┬─┐
│1 1 1│3 3│1 1│2 2 2│1 1│3│
└─────┴───┴───┴─────┴───┴─┘
   f 'ABBBCDXYYZ'
┌─┬───┬─┬─┬─┬──┬─┐
│A│BBB│C│D│X│YY│Z│
└─┴───┴─┴─┴─┴──┴─┘
   f 0
┌─┐
│0│
└─┘
```

### Explanation

```
<;.1~1,2~:/\]  Input: s
            ]  Identify function to get s
       2       The constant 2
           \   Operate on each overlapping sublist of size 2
        ~:/      Are the two values unequal, 1 if true else 0
     1,        Prepend a 1 to it
<;.1~          Using the list just made, chop s at each index equal to 1 and box it
               Return this as the result
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 9 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

```
⊢⊂⍨1,2≠/⊢
```

`⊢` the argument
`⊂⍨` partitioned at
`1` at the first element
`,` and then
`2≠/` where subsequent pairs differ
`⊢` in the argument

Answer (score 3):

## gs2, 2 bytes

```
c-
```

[Try it online!](http://gs2.tryitonline.net/#code=Yy0&input=SGVsbG9-d29vb29vcmxkIQ)

`c` is a grouping built-in that does exactly this, so we call it on STDIN (which is a string, i.e., a list of chars) and get a list of strings. Sadly, the result is indistinguishable from the input, so we need to add separators! `-` (join by spaces) does the trick.

An alternative answer is `cα` (2 bytes of CP437), which simply wraps `c` into an anonymous function.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 13 bytes

```
:{s.dl1}fs.c?
```

**Warning:** this is extremely inefficient, and you will understand why in the explanation.

This expects a list (e.g `[1:1:2:2:2]`) as input. The elements inside the list can be pretty much anything.

#### Explanation

```
:{     }f       Find all ordered subsets of the Input with a unique element in them
  s.                Output is a subset of the input
    dl1             Output minus all duplicates has a length of 1 (i.e. one unique value)
         s.     Output is an ordered subset of those subsets
           c?   The concatenation of those subsets is the Input
```

This works only because of the way `s - Subset` unifies: the smallest sets are at the end. Therefore the first thing it finds that concatenates to the Input are the longest runs, e.g. `[[1:1]:[2:2:2]]` and not for example `[[1:1]:[2:2]:[2]]`.

Answer (score 2):

### Python 2, 43 bytes

```python
p=-1
for x in input():print"|"[:x^p],x,;p=x
```

Works on lists of booleans. Example:

```python
>> [True,True,False,False,False,True,False,True,False]
 True  True | False  False  False | True | False | True | False
```

Iterates through the input list, storing the last seen element. A separator bar is printed before each element that is different than the previous, checked as having bitwise xor `^` of 0. Initializing `p=-1` avoids a separator before the first element.

Comment: Too bad `groupby` is such a pain...

Answer (score 2):

### CJam, 9 bytes

Two solutions:

```
{e`:a:e~}
{e`{(*}%}
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%5B1%201%201%203%203%201%201%202%202%202%201%201%203%5D%0A%0A%7Be%60%3Aa%3Ae~%7D%0A%20%20%20%0A%0A~p)

#### Explanation

```
e`   e# Run-length encode (gives a list of pairs [run-length value]).
:a   e# Wrap each pair in a singleton list.
:e~  e# Run-length decode each list.
```

Or

```
e`   e# Run-length encode.
{    e# Map this block over each pair...
  (  e#   Pull out the run length.
  *  e#   Repeat the list containing only the value that many times.
}%
```

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 22 bytes

```haskell
import Data.List
group
```

There's a built-in. Works on any type that supports equality.

Comment: Any reason why this is community wiki?

Comment: @Fatalize [Anyone who knows Haskell could have posted it.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30801907#30801907)

Comment: That's noble but since no one else is doing it, why don't you ask about that on meta?

Answer (score 2):

## MATL, <s>8</s> 7 bytes

Removed 1 byte thanks to @Suever

```
ly&Y'Y{
```

Works with integers/floats/chars/booleans/unicorn points/other imaginary inputs.
For booleans, inputs are `T/F`, outputs are `1/0`.

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=bHkmWSdZew&input=WzEsIDEsIDEsIDMsIDMsIDEsIDEsIDIsIDIsIDIsIDEsIDEsIDNd)

---

**Grouped and Repeated**

```
ly&Y'Y{
l          % push 1 onto the stack
 y         % duplicate the input
  &Y'      % run-length encoding (secondary output only)
     Y{    % break up array into cell array of subarrays
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 28 bytes

```sh
>$1;for i {mv * $i&&echo;ls}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@F@cWqJgCIZGQGgMhiYKlv/tVAyt0/KLFDIVqnPLFLQUVDLV1FKTM/Ktc4pr/xflKmj9//8fAA)

- `>$1`: create the file named the first argument
- `for i {}`: for each argument:

  - `mv * $i`: attempt to move all files in the current directory to the current item
  - If these are the same (i.e. this item is the same as the last), this will fail with `mv: 'X' and 'X' are the same file`.
  - `&&`: if this doesn't fail (i.e. this item is not the same as the last)

    - `echo`: print a blank line to separate the runs
  - `ls`: then list all the files in the current directory. In effect, this just prints `$i`.

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://git.sr.ht/%7Engn/k), 12 bytes

```
{(&~~':x)_x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k#eJx9UMFqwzAMvfsrRA/zBh5LUzuJexg0CfuCHZIaM3ZYTzttDApj/fZJlh07lA2JJ1vv6cn4tP++vblc5P5893L+EeLkNGioMSxYj9ctUFBjF0JzZIqaSVJzh0gLLXTQgKGLAcOHzaHv+2Gc5vm4yRYVRkIMIlTlhXgQTivArENaTA/3j+BC2ytwRFANlBduq4CTJ3Yp9ZLRIApLjyimYyEvTVlRLqgX6to3mZV74qpFQvb49lZBp6BR+ElsY4ltCTqChsCQ2KAmy9INCXmQCmS/hoFgJJgI5gWOMjrgGHmvBkNj4DJymbhEg3BGC1z7/PH1pqDEp9f3z1z+7mWMT7lq45ZykO7/9Vez+LQq+lbe/wIvwKsI)

A relatively straightforward "idiom". A (verbose) q version is:

```
{(where differ x)cut x}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 1 byte

```
g
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8X/6////o6NNdEx0jIDQUscyVifaUAcEQXxjMDSBQLgMSAymwggiApSz1DHXsdAx0zEFsk11TMG0QWwsAA) for all the integer test-cases, or [here](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P/3////RSiFFpalKOmiUW2JOMTKNXxiZigUA) for the "True/False" one

From the [Husk Wiki](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk/wiki/Commands):
`g`  `group`  Group equal adjacent values

---

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 10 bytes

```
CẊ-Θ:W≠¹L¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/3/nhri7dczOswh91Lji00@fQzv///0cb6oCgERAaQ6GJjkksAA)

Without `g`...

From the Husk wiki:

```
C            Cut off sublists of input, in lengths given by:
 Ẋ             Map over pairs of adjacent values:
  -              Subtract first argument from second
                 (so Ẋ- = differences)
   Θ           Prepends a falsy value (here = zero) to
    :   L¹     Append the length of the input to
     W≠¹       Indices of input that are not equal to their successor
```

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 32 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/(.)(?!\1)/g,'$1 ')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fU5da8JAEHz3V2yhcBc440f9bNHSKoW@98E2DRjiKZEjSe9OEYq/3e4mp8ZKC8vs3ezszK6jbWRineS2nmYLeViODmY0Nr6WuYpiyRvc9/jjzWfLa6wEu20B8w5xlhoLWkYLlaQSRvj82iRacnbkmPdQcypVzEvaj/Fl5WtqpV6S@3cNIEnzjb2HXGexNMY3dpGkAvlsY38PkKrt0VorP0s5K5LEbjQmm22kwWLWzje5Sixn9TFdAUB3ZEr6KlvxJZfbSHEbNEPPX2dJOp97KNp7h6AjAKtd1BArhPoYgoIOBQQ0oF6MwlrQElBWuXF3rM6pnIETVj2cmJ4VedW0VFQD2qfRte/RrJrjok4Sssfb@wIGAnoCus5mSNM@wYCgR9AlcRc1Z9nxhwP2xASw50uYEEwJZgTvJ/hgzgHXyPtisSAmZZuWbVY2Z1C80QJj3/RGCqjiS6TMuf3NndGdckVjSnWR/v/xF7t4WtP5NsPwBw)

Support char

Answer (score 1):

### C#, 117 bytes

```
void f(List<String>m){Console.Write(m[0]+String.Join("",m.GetRange(1,m.Count()-1).Select((i,j)=>i==m[j]?i:"\n"+i)));}
```

ungolfed (not really)

```
    public static void f(List<String>m)
    {
        Console.Write(m[0]+String.Join("",m.GetRange(1,m.Count()-1).Select((i,j)=>i==m[j]?i:"\n"+i)));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pyth), <strike>36</strike> 35 bytes

```
VQIqNk=hZ).?=+Y]*]kZ=Z1=kN;t+Y]*]kZ
```

[Test link](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VQIqNk%3DhZ%29.%3F%3D%2BY]*]kZ%3DZ1%3DkN%3Bt%2BY]*]kZ&input=[1%2C1%2C1%2C2%2C2%2C3%2C3%2C3%2C1]&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=[4%2C+4%2C+2%2C+2%2C+9%2C+9]%0A[1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+2%2C+2%2C+3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4]%0A[1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+3%2C+3%2C+1%2C+1%2C+2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+1%2C+1%2C+3]%0A[9%2C+7%2C+8%2C+6%2C+5]%0A[5%2C+5%2C+5]%0A[%27A%27%2C+%27B%27%2C+%27B%27%2C+%27B%27%2C+%27C%27%2C+%27D%27%2C+%27X%27%2C+%27Y%27%2C+%27Y%27%2C+%27Z%27]+%0A[0]&debug=0)

Edit: explanation:

```
                                      standard variables: Y=[], Z=0, k='', Q=input
VQ                                    iterate over input
  IqNk                                if the current entity is equal to k:
      =hZ)                            increase Z.
          .?                          else:
               ]*]kZ                  list of length Z filled with k
            =+Y                       add it to Y
                    =Z1               set Z to 1
                       =kN            set k to the current entity
                          ;           end loop
                              ]*]kZ   list of length Z filled with k
                            +Y        add it to Y
                           t          implicitly print the tail of Y (removing the first element)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, <s>9</s> 7 bytes

```
mr9]dr8
```

Credit to @LeakyNun for 2 byte!

Explanation:

```
             input
     r8      run-length decode
m            for each...
   ]d        ...treat each run as standalone encoded form...
 r9          ...decode 
             print
```

---

#### Old answer, 12 bytes

```
hf.Am!t{dT./
```

Forgot about run length built-in, but I think this is an okay approach, so I kept it.

Explanation:

```
                input
          ./    all possible partitions
 f       T      filter by...
  .A            ...whether all groups of integers...
    m!t{d       ...have length one after deduplication
h               get the first element (first one has no adjacent [1,1] and [1])
                print
```

Comment: [This](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=rR9%5DMr8&input=1%2C1%2C1%2C2%2C2%2C2%2C3%2C1%2C4%2C3%2C2%2C1&debug=0) is 7 bytes

Comment: @LeakyNun Oh right! That's cool.

Comment: I believe [this](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=mM_Mr8&input=%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C2%2C2%2C2%2C3%2C1%2C4%2C3%2C2%2C1%5D&debug=0) works for 6.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Nice abuse of `m`.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Wow, I don't understand o.O

Comment: It's a trick to rld slightly more efficiently. When you rle you get a list with elements like `[repetitions, value]`. Reversing that and then splatting it over the map function results in: `m<value><repetitions>` which returns the list we want.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Wow, so that's how a higher-order function interacts with a function suffix! I've always wanted to figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>24</s> 22 bytes

2 bytes thanks to Martin Ender.

A [15-byte answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/84423/48934) already exists, so this is just another approach which costs more bytes.

```
S-`(?<=(\d+)) (?!\1\b)
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=Uy1gKD88PShcZCspKSAoPyFcMVxiKQ&input=MSAxIDEgMiAyIDMgMyAzIDQgOQ)

It splits on spaces whose preceding number differ from the proceeding.

This is a demonstration of lookarounds.

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>88</s> 77 bytes

*Moved the* `strmcmp` *inside the* `printf` *saving 11 bytes*

```
f(char**a){*a++;char*x;for(;*a;x=*a++)printf(strcmp(*a,x)?"\n%s ":"%s ",*a);}
```

#### Usage:

```
f(char**a){*a++;char*x;for(;*a;x=*a++)printf(strcmp(*a,x)?"\n%s ":"%s ",*a);}
main(c,v)char**v;{f(v);}
```

#### Sample Input:

*(command line parameters)*

```
1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 5 6 7777
```

#### Sample Output:

```
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3
4
5
6
7777
```

**Tested on:**

```
gcc 4.4.7 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)  - OK
gcc 5.3.0 (Cygwin)            - Segmetation Fault
gcc 4.8.1 (Windows)           - OK
```

I'm trying to fix the 5.3.0 Segmetation Fault.

**88 Version**

```
f(char**a){*a++;char*x;for(;*a;x=*a++)strcmp(*a,x)?printf("\n%s ",*a):printf("%s ",*a);}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 134 bytes

```
void a(String[]a){int i=0,l=a.length;for(;i<l-1;i++)System.out.print(a[i]+((a[i].equals(a[i+1]))?" ":"\n"));System.out.print(a[l-1]);}
```

iterates through, and decides whether to separate with a new line or a space.

Comment: for starter you could remove `public` and `static` keywords. also you could remove curly brackets in for loop

Comment: Done @user902383

Answer (score 1):

### 05AB1E, 13 bytes

```
¬svyÊi¶}yðJ?y
```

**Explained**

```
¬s             # push first element of list to stack and swap with input
  v            # for each X in input
   yÊi¶}       # if X is different from last iteration, push a newline
        yðJ?   # push X followed by a space to stack and join stack to string
            y  # push X to stack for next iterations comparison
```

Should work for any list.
Tested on int and char.

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=wqxzdnnDimnCtn15w7BKP3k&input=WydBJywgJ0InLCAnQicsICdCJywgJ0MnLCAnRCcsICdYJywgJ1knLCAnWScsICdaJ10)

Answer (score 1):

## Swift, 43 bytes

```
var p=0;i.map{print($0==p ?"":",",$0);p=$0}
```

Assumes i to be an array of equatable objects; works for anything from ints to strings to custom objects. Kind of cheeky in that the output contains lots of newlines, but making that prettier would cost bytes.

**Prettier, ungolfed version:**

```
var prev = Int.max // unlikely to be the first element, but not the end of the world if it happens to be.
i.map { n in
    print(n == prev ? " " : "\n•", n, terminator: "")
    prev = n
}
```

This version prints every group on a new line at the expense of more code.

### Ideas for Improvement

```
i.reduce(0){print($0==$1 ?"":"•",$1);return $1}
```

This version has 47 bytes, but it's a different approach, so maybe there's something to optimize away there? The biggest problem is the return statement.

Answer (score 1):

### [ListSharp](https://github.com/timopomer/ListSharp), 134 bytes

```
STRG l = READ[<here>+"\\l.txt"]
[FOREACH NUMB IN 1 TO l LENGTH-1 AS i]
{
[IF l[i] ISNOT l[i-1]]
STRG o=o+"\n"
STRG o=o+l[i]
}
SHOW = o
```

ListSharp doesnt support functions so the array is saved in a local file called `l.txt`
[image: file]

Answer (score 1):

## **[Ruby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_(programming_language)), 24 bytes**

In ruby `Array` instances have built-in method `group_by`

So solution will be:

```
a.group_by{|x| x}.values
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
Œg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opPT/h9sfNa05Ounhzhn//0eb6CgAkREYWQJRrI5CtKGOAgRBhI1hyASOYgE)

Alternatively, a non-builtin approach:

```
Ik
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98z@//h9kdNa45Oerhzxv//0SY6CkBkBEaWQBSroxBtqKMAQRBhYxgygaNYAA)

Comment: "Alternatively, a non-builtin approach". Nonsense. Even if you expand every single step to the most basic of operations, Jelly will always be a builtin.

Comment: @EasyasPi Yeah, but the same applies for all languages. `str.replace` in Python is just as much a builtin as `I` in Jelly. The second answer just shows that there is a way to do the task without a single command that does what’s asked for

Comment: It was a joke, but yeah, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com), 1 byte

```
Ġ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C4%A0&inputs=%5B1%2C%201%2C%201%2C%203%2C%203%2C%201%2C%201%2C%202%2C%202%2C%202%2C%201%2C%201%2C%203%5D&header=&footer=)

Ah yes, the power of triviality.

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 49 bytes

```powershell
$args|%{,$a*!($i=$_-in$a-or!$a)
$a=$a*$i+,$_}
,$a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVJLT4NAEL7zK6bNVkCXpPbdQxO0TRNPGuuhagzBulUaCnWBqGn57Ti7CwSaVMlkBr7XbMjuwi/Gow/m@xlZwwT2GXH5e3Ro7SlxzxsG8SbEsbyAuFbIG8Q1NeJOkCHeBSVOqqEqSzVt7fkx4zAP@daNrZsgwI89NA3imE1A3jY0ahg9ClgdWWMsk4LExBSomBI3hfqSgipl6BbVK0voc1U1IlcW6bm2nqk01fxOSR3FditQsSbfVEpUOp59SGFEYUChj7htjGUfyj6SfSB7Xxn6qFPS8lXi@pVOQb@ut6loM9GWoj2W7UmXmWgSQTWbIqb5nOVzqYR5gsIwRK4mDzxhFI7G3PWj6vwbrgyx6BRcc8tTFJx9kjyKEUe2jbbk2/hlwgFasNcAH7zI3P1BJfvesVXM3vB6E0dRnEWJHyNwhrfelkJJPN8tpkkUh9vb1w16XmwVJZ5FslqxKEIP/iTlP1Tvu2ltQi8Qv9QEi30KVbH4lK7Mvi@O80@yNKRamv0C)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 1 [byte](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ġ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDNCVBMSZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PSU1QjElMkMlMjAxJTJDJTIwMSUyQyUyMDMlMkMlMjAzJTJDJTIwMSUyQyUyMDElMkMlMjAyJTJDJTIwMiUyQyUyMDIlMkMlMjAxJTJDJTIwMSUyQyUyMDMlNUQmZmxhZ3M9)

Answer (score 0):

## TSQL, 132 bytes

This is a little different from the other answers - sql doesn't have arrays, the obvious input for sql is a table.

**Golfed:**

```
DECLARE @ table(i int identity, v varchar(20))
INSERT @ values(1),(1),(1),(3),(3),(1),(1),(2),(2),(2),(1),(1),(3)

SELECT REPLICATE(v+' ',COUNT(*))FROM(SELECT i,i-row_number()over(partition
by v order by i)x,v FROM @)z GROUP BY x,v ORDER BY max(i)
```

**Ungolfed:**

```
DECLARE @ table(i int identity, v varchar(20))
INSERT @ values(1),(1),(1),(3),(3),(1),(1),(2),(2),(2),(1),(1),(3)

SELECT
  REPLICATE(v+' ',COUNT(*))
FROM 
  (
     SELECT
       i,
       i-row_number()over(partition by v order by i)x,
       v
     FROM @
  )z
GROUP BY
  x,v
ORDER BY
  max(i)
```

**[Fiddle](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/507682/groups-of-repeating-items)**

Answer (score 0):

### Perl 5 - 39 Bytes

```
print$_.($/)[$_ eq@a[++$-]]for@a=sort@a
```

Answer (score 0):

## sed, <s>33</s> 23+1=24 bytes

```
s/([^ ]+)( \1)* */&\n/g
```

It needs the `-r` option.

Usage example:

```
$ echo '1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 9 9' | sed -r 's/([^ ]+)( \1)* */&\n/g'
1 1 1 
2 2 
3 3 3 
4 
9 9
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke, 2 bytes (non competitive)

Only supports integers

```
$f
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%24f&input=%5B4%2C+4%2C+2%2C+2%2C+9%2C+9%5D)

```
split_at(input, delta(input))
```

Added split_at node, splits input when 2nd arg is truthy

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 56

Input: array of numbers or strings

Output: array of arrays

First time ever using exact comparisong in golfed code

```
a=>a.map(x=>x!==p?o.push(g=[p=x]):g.push(x),p=o=g=[])&&o
```

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure, 19 bytes

```
#(partition-by + %)
```

It's a built-in, but it takes a mapping function.  In this case, `+` serves as an identity function.

Answer (score 0):

### [Befunge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Befunge), <s>47</s> <s>41</s> 38 Bytes

```
&:&:.92pv.<
g29:&:-1_@|!-
92p25*,.^ >:
```

Input format:

```
number_of_values-1         values (separated by a space)
```

You may test the code [here](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/befunge.html)

---

Previous version with explanations :

```
&:&:.00pv.<
g00:&:-1_@|!-
v*52p00:  <
>,.     ^
```

The interpet's cursor follows the symbols `> v < ^`. If the cursor is at the end of a line and is going to the right, it will loop back to the beginning (same principle for other directions).

`&:` : Gets the first input put it to the stack and duplicates it (to the stack)

`&:.00pv` : Gets the second input, prints it and saves it into the code, at the coordinates (0,0) [erasing the first '&']. Then, go down

`_` : Test if last value of the stack (the number of values) is equals to 0 and set the cursor's direction to the right if it is, to the left if it isn't

`1-:` : Removes 1 from the number of values

`&:00g-!|` : Compares the next input with the one stored at (0,0). Set the cursor's direction to up if they are equal, to down if they aren't

`.` : Displays a numeric value

`:00p52*,.` : Override the last saved value to the current value, then displays `\n` (ascii 10, 5*2) followed by the value

`@` : Terminates the program

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript (using external library) (178 bytes)

```
(s)=>_.From(s).Aggregate((t,e)=>{if(0===t.Items.length)return t.Items.push([e]),t;var s=t.Items[t.Items.length-1];return s[0]===e?(s.push(e),t):(t.Items.push([e]),t)},{Items:[]})
```

Disclaimer: I am using a library I wrote to implement LINQ from C# into JS. It didn't exactly help me win but oh well

[image]

[image: Image2]

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 1 [byte](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
γ
```

Builtins ftw ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3Ob//6MNdUDQGAhBtBEYgkViAQ) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/c5v/6/yPjjbRMdExAkJLHctYnWhDHRAE8Y3B0AQC4TIgMZgKI4gIUM5Sx1zHQsdMxxTINtUxBdNKjko6Sk5I2BmIXYA4AogjoThKCaQypKg0FchBpdwSc4qRafzCyBTQSAOsXgF5MDYWAA).

Here an alternative without builtins (**6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)**):

```
üÊ0šÅ¡
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8J7DXQZHFx5uPbTw//9oQx0QNAZCEG0EhmCRWAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXL/8N7DncZHF14uPXQwv86/6OjTXRMdIyA0FLHMlYn2lAHBEF8YzA0gUC4DEgMpsIIIgKUs9Qx17HQMdMxBbJNdUzBtJKjko6SExJ2BmIXII4A4kgojlICqQwpKk0FclApt8ScYmQavzAyBTTSAKtXQB6MjQUA).

**Explanation:**

```python
γ       # Split the (implicit) input-list into chunks of equal adjacent values
        # (after which the resulting list of lists is output implicitly)

ü       # For each overlapping pair of values in the (implicit) input-list:
 Ê      #  Check that they are NOT equal (0 if equal; 1 if not)
  0š    # Prepend a 0 to this list
    Å¡  # Split the (implicit) input-list at the truthy indices
        # (after which the resulting list of lists is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 54 bytes

```c
f(char*s){printf("%c%c",*s,*s-s[1]?10:32),*++s&&f(s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYxBCoMwFET3nuITUJKokJjWlobSg4gL@TStiwbJ15V49jS6KX0MAzMMg/ULMUbH8T0ESWKdwuhnx1mOObJKUlJNne4fWt1MIypZllQUjpOwW0xT@Ayj5wLWLIPEfgPU9XAHppvGGHNKnK@Jtm2VujB77A6blpn2o1/j/mN4zkvwoGy2xS8)

or **55 bytes** iteratively

```c
f(char*s){while(printf("%c%c",*s,*s-s[1]?10:32),*++s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NIzkjsUirWLO6PCMzJ1WjoCgzryRNQ0k1WTVZSUerGIh0i6MNY@0NDayMjTR1tLS1izWta/8DVSnkJmbmaWgqVHNxKQAByByF4uhYBVsFJUMjI2NjYxMgMLUAAjMzMwMDcyVrsDowUVBaUqwBNAghkobKLUotKS3KUzCw5qr9DwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 35 bytes

```
≔⁰ξ≔⁺θ θＦ⊖Ｌθ«¿¬⁼§θι§θ⊕ι«Ｐ✂θξ⊕ι↓≔⊕ιξ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY6xCoMwFEXn5CuK03ug0LmbYAeh7dKxdEiTqIE0MRqtUPz21FBBSs90L5wLlzes45bpEPK@V7WBfTohXXMuBLg02SWYOqSV7aCQvJNPabwUcJKm9g04RHxToiq4WA9HNzDdQ@5LI@S0rBWmWynNNleI3yU5D9qrtlPGw1UrLhdx@lOjZ0cJh8K@TGzrx18vnieEkpnOIdwStvBY4JHkHjI9hixrW15/AA) Link is to verbose version of code.

Input as a list of characters.

Answer (score 0):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog) v2, 1 byte

```
ḅ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3w/@GO1v//o6NNdEx0jIDQUscyVifaUAcEQXxjMDSBQLgMSAymwggiApSz1DHXsdAx0zEFsk11TMG0kqOSjpITEnYGYhcgjgDiSCiOUgKpDCkqTQVyUCm3xJxiZBq/MDIFNNIAq1dAHoyNBQA)

Less built-in and far, far slower:

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog) v2, 4 bytes

```
~c=ᵐ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3wvy7ZFkT9j4420THRMQJCSx3LWJ1oQx0QBPGNwdAEAuEyIDGYCiOICFDOUsdcx0LHTMcUyDbVMQXTSo5KOkpOSNgZiF2AOAKII6E4SgmkMqSoNBXIQaXcEnOKkWn8wsgU0EgDrF4BeTA2FgA)

```
~c      The output is a partitioning of the input (with as few partitions as possible)
   ᵐ    such that each partition
  =     contains only one unique element.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 23 bytes

```
[ [ ] group-by values ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/NC4JAEMXv/hXD3pMy@7BOfUB06RJBJR42WUUo3XbXSMS/fRttV2p@vGF4710mobEqhD4d94fdAqiURSwhFUXJszx12VsJKoELplTFRZYrkOxZsjxmEpZO7QBODT7iIQHSGG/U0brjDt/wn7eJ7XnGsY0AZjCHKUx6h6wIkPWPNqgt6oy6GF1J31cdCWJ3i02H/dU4jQ4hhOj7@eBWwYveS/wx0g/KwdUf)

```
[                        ! begin quotation (anonymous function)
  [ ]                    ! A quotation that returns its input
      group-by           ! group adjacent elements with a ( key -- value ) quotation
               values    ! obtain the values of an associative array
                      ]  ! end quotation
```

Factor actually has a combinator called `monotonic-split` that can do this more directly, but it's more bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 16 bytes

```arturo
$=>[chunk&=>[&]]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?qyAiFC)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 2 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 1.65 bytes

```
zy
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhaLqiohDCh_wU31aEMdBQgyBiMI2wiGoFKxEPUA)

Built-in solution.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 2 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Can handle all data types.

```
òÀ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=8sA&input=WzQsIDQsIDIsIDIsIDksIDldCi1R)

```
òÀ     :Implicit input of array
ò      :Partition between elements
 À     :That are not strictly equal
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 83 bytes

```java
s->{char a=0;for(char b:s.toCharArray())System.out.print((a<1|a==b?"":" ")+(a=b));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7NDoIwEITP@hSbntoYiF7FaoxXPHE0HrYtaJG/tIWEKM9eGyRxTruz2ZmvxAGjUr1814tKS5AVWgtX1A2812sI0o3LTYEyhzRYsGhotYKCZs7o5gGWJfNl@r1Yhy5kpVAB9zY6vuUTDSDfJkVr6LyIvY1dewnj2RgcKWPZaF1ex23v4i6EOkrxsPsg5@JEyJ4AYRuKXDCWTP7XtiAvbTNRHcAXqNsd0DwsC9CrKi4oQSGklEop8qed/Bc)

---

Alternative solution using Streams (**85 bytes**) :

```java
s->s.chars().reduce(0,(a,b)->{System.out.print((a<1|a==b?"":" ")+(char)b);return b;})
```

Don't hesitate to ask if this needs any explanation!

Answer (score 0):

## F#, 196 bytes

```
let g x=Seq.foldBack(fun n c->Seq.tryHead c|>function|None->[n,1];|Some i when fst i<>n->(n,1)::c;|_->Seq.head c|>fun h->(fst h,(snd h)+1)::(List.tail c))x []|>Seq.map(fun(i,c)->Seq.replicate c i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVFdT4MwFH3nV5wsWaBxbG5ufqxKsunDHowve1EJMaQr0sjKhC7OhP@OLTCYJpKT095z7j1puFHusjTjZZlwhXcc7tb8cxilyWYZsg8n2ktIMNczqsq@VzzcgBWe1pkSqSyeUsldz5eDcUCLdbrlEPiKuUSUK4hbT7qeo00ynzNavNU5cReCWPumNR44udwgJmem13kUuRqqUCRghBzgB0U1uQ135kmOGDBSZ2V8lwgWKg4GQUrfgv78KYXGpMKNRlDLY4oatXNxxLTF38baPx2atFbTq/OvKK4pLilmjTbT1646D6zRqLrZC5vCXv6me0MPhp4NvbT0areDKttzilOOwiTvjv@1jgMrsAoPzX9Es1vXg16Q3rzEqVntOzVrIEe9KckxRCie1SkmIOP5PtHNOm@XCakiiV5/Ycr@oqfDG7/8AQ) (includes character and boolean tests cases in the footer, but others must be commented out first).

Essentially, it counts the number of sequential items in the collection, then creates a new collection of each item replicated for their respective counts.

Answer (score 0):

## [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) (Type System) 4.9.5 - <strike>156</strike> 121 Bytes

- 35 Bytes thanks to **ASCII-only**

```
type F<X,Y=[],Z=any>=X extends[infer A,...infer B]?[Z]extends[A]?Y extends[...infer C,infer D]?F<B,[...C,[...D, A]],A>:F<B,[...Y,[A]],A>:F<B,[...Y,[A]],A>:Y
```

**Un-golfed version**

```
type DistinctGroups<
  Input extends number[],
  Output extends number[][] = [],
  LastElement extends any = never
>=
  Input extends [infer First, ...infer Rest] ?
    [LastElement] extends [First] ?
      Output extends [...infer Head, infer Tail] ?
        DistinctGroups<Rest, [...Head, [...Tail, First]], First> :
        DistinctGroups<Rest, [...Output, [First]], First>
    : DistinctGroups<Rest, [...Output, [First]], First>
  : Output
```

[Try it on the TypeScript playground!](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1&ssl=1&ssc=122&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgPADQDQE0C8BtAukgWmgBgD40EoIAPYCAOwBMBnDASxoDMIAnKAQSQDpBrDtwBCWAPzxRSDLlRZK1ekz4ZB-YVygBhJFu4ARLJPWC9Z-oaQ8TALkspZtnDyJ2UAKE+hIUACoAjFBosHAYgUhQkdFRAEzxUQDMyalQACxRAJxYRJ4A9PlQxQB6Ej7g0P5xIWERuQVFpeW+VUm18BFRgQ2FxVBlFX7+6R3hMTEJUCnTvU0DLZUBAKxj2Hl9zUA)

Comment: [121?](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1&ssl=1&ssc=122&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgPADQDQE0C8BtAukgWmgBgD40EoIAPYCAOwBMBnDASxoDMIAnKAQSQDpBrDtwBCWAPzxRSDLlRZK1ekz4ZB-YVygBhJFu4ARLJPWC9Z-oaQ8TALkspZtnDyJ2UAKE+hIUACoAjFBosHAYgUhQkdFRAEzxUQDMyalQACxRAJxYRJ4A9PlQxQB6Ej7g0P5xIWERuQVFpeW+VUm18BFRgQ2FxVBlFX7+6R3hMTEJUCnTvU0DLZUBAKxj2Hl9zUA)

Comment: @ASCII-only just updated!

Comment: missing byte count?! (you might've also forgotten to update the code in the snippet, and the explanation)

Answer (score 0):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 15 bytes

Returns an Enumerator.

```ruby
:slice_when+:!=
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboW662KczKTU-PLM1LztK0UoaI39QoU3KKjDXUUIMgIjIxhyASOYmP1SvLjEyG6FiyA0AA)