# Chunk + Enumerate a list of digits

Tags: code-golf, array

I have a list of decimal digits:

`4, 4, 4, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4`

The list of decimal digits are known as items. We can form "chunks" from these items by grouping together identical and adjacent numbers. I want to assign each chunk a unique number, starting from 1, and increasing by 1 in the order the chunks appear in the original list. So, the output for the given example would look like this:

`1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5`

### Input format

A list of digits. (0-9) You may use your language built-ins to read this list however you want. Encoding: ASCII

## Output format

A series of decimal numbers, separated by a delimiter. Your program must always use the same delimiter. The delimiter must be longer than 0 bits. Encoding: ASCII

Standard loopholes apply.

Comment: Any particular reason for the strict input and output format?

Comment: @UnrelatedString Hmm, I shall loosen them.

Comment: Can the output start from 0 instead?

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance No.

Comment: Can we start the output sequence from `0`? Can we output a 2D-array?

Comment: @Shaggy Embodiment just asked about 0 and was answered!

Comment: @Adám: Ah, hadn't refreshed. Thanks.

Comment: The IO is still rather strict. Can't you just say "input and output is as a list" and let the site defaults take care of it for you?

Comment: Can we assume the list is non-empty?

Comment: "The delimiter must be longer than 0 bits" — probably bytes? Because (ASCII) character is a byte, not a bit!

Comment: @JoKing edited!

Comment: You only changed the input section and not the output part

Comment: @JoKing outputting with stuff before or after is allowed

Comment: I don't understand why you keep going on about delimiters. Are you implying that we have to be outputting to STDOUT, or that functions have to return a string? If not, then why not just simplify it and just *say* "Input is a list of digits"

Comment: @JoKing Delimiters are not mentioned in the input section. The output or its string representation must have delimiters by definition because the number of chunks can exceed 9, and be multi-digit.

Comment: A list *by definition* has delimiters already. That's why it's a list. I also don't understand what you mean by `You may use your language built-ins to read this list however you want.`. Does that mean we have to include a string to list converter in our submission? And *are* we allowed to output as a list?

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 41 bytes

```python
lambda l,n=0:[n:=n+(l!=(l:=x))for x in l]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPqfZhvzPycxNyklUSFHJ8/WwCo6z8o2T1sjR9FWI8fKtkJTMy2/SKFCITNPISf2f45ttImOAgSZg5ElEjKCIZCCWK6Cosy8Eo00jRxNzf8A)

Praise the magic walrus `:=` of assignment expressions.

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 42 bytes

```python
n=0
for x in input():n+=x!=id;id=x;print n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8/WgCstv0ihQiEzD4gKSks0NK3ytG0rFG0zU6wzU2wrrAuKMvNKFPL@/4821FGAICMwMkZCJjBkCkSxAA)

Comment: Hmm, how long would this be in Pyth?

Comment: Huh, I avoided `id` because it's 2 bytes long...

Comment: Oof nice idea of `id`

Comment: @noɥʇʎԀʎzɐɹƆ 8 bytes for a straightforward translation: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P9dWOyovxDbk//9oEx0FCDIHI0skZARDIAWxAA "Pyth – Try It Online")

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 44 bytes

```python
l=input()
n=0
for i in l:n+=i!=l;l=i;print n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8c2M6@gtERDkyvP1oArLb9IIVMhM08hxypP2zZT0TbHGqjAuqAoM69EIe//fw0THQUIMgcjSyRkBEMgBZoA)

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (dzaima/APL)](https://github.com/dzaima/APL), 7 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function. Prints space-separated.

```apl
+\1,2≠/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pSszMTfyf9qhtgsZ/7RhDHaNHnQv0/2v@T1Mw0YEiczCyREJGMARS8C@/oCQzP6/4v24xAA)

`2≠/` pair-wise inequality

`1,` prepend 1

`+\` cumulative sum

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
ŒɠµJx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opJMLDm31qvj//3@0iY4CBJmDkSUSMoIhqIJYAA)

Saved one byte thanks to [UnrelatedString](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/85334/unrelated-string)!

Inputs and outputs as array's (with opening/closing brackets)

### How it works

```
ŒɠµJx - Main link, takes one argument:                       [7, 7, 5, 5, 5, 1]
Œɠ    - Get the lengths of consecutive elements:             [2, 3, 1]
  µ   - Call these lengths A
   J  - range(length(A))                                     [1, 2, 3]
    x - Repeat each element by the corresponding value in A: [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
```

Comment: [5 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opJMLDm31qvj//3@0iY4CBJmDkSUSMoIhkIJYAA)

Comment: @UnrelatedString all these new-fangled atoms!

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ŒgƤẈ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opPRjSx7u6vj//3@0iY4CBJmDkSUSMoIhqIJYAA)**

#### How?

```
ŒgƤẈ - Link: list of integers  e.g. [7,7,2,7,7]
  Ƥ  - for prefixes:     [7]   [7,7]   [7,7,2]      [7,7,2,7]        [7,7,2,7,7]
Œg   -   group runs      [[7]] [[7,7]] [[7,7],[2]]  [[7,7],[2],[7]]  [[7,7],[2],[7,7]]
   Ẉ - length of each    [1,   1,      2,           3,               3]
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 30 bytes

Takes input as an array of integers.

```javascript
a=>a.map(p=n=>i+=p!=(p=n),i=0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1i5RLzexQKPANs/WLlPbtkDRFsTW1Mm0NdD8n5yfV5yfk6qXk5@ukaYRbaKjAEHmYGSJhIxgCKQgVlPzPwA)

#### Commented

```javascript
a =>                // a[] = input array
  a.map(p =         // initialize p to a non-numeric value
  n =>              // for each value n in a[]:
    i +=            //   increment i if:
      p != (p = n), //     p is not equal to n; and update p to n
    i = 0           //   start with i = 0 (chunk counter)
  )                 // end of map()
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) / MATLAB, 25 bytes

```matlab
@(x)cumsum([1 ~~diff(x)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0IzuTS3uDRXI9pQoa4uJTMtDSgUq/k/TSPaREcBgszByBIJGcEQSAFQNQA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 29 bytes

```
Join@@(i=1;0#+i++&/@Split@#)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE7876Zg@98rPzPPwUEj09bQ2kBZO1NbW03fIbggJ7PEQVlTDajCQaHaREcBgszByBIJGcEQSEHt//@6BUWZeSUA)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
¥Ā.¥>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0NIjDXqHltr9/x9toqMAQeZgZImEjGAIqiAWAA)

Comment: Minor 5-bytes alternative: `¥Ā` could also be `üÊ`.

Comment: [4 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/189983/6484)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 40 bytes

```hs
f(a:t)=1:map(+sum[1|a/=t!!0])(f t)
f e=e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00j0apE09bQKjexQEO7uDQ32rAmUd@2RFHRIFZTI02hRJMrTSHVNvV/bmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JgopCmkK0iY4CBJmDkSUSMoIhkILY//@S03IS04v/6yYXFAAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 21 bytes

```perl6
{+<<[\+] $,|$_ Zne$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv1rbxiY6RjtWQUWnRiVeISovVSW@9n9xYqVCmka0iY4CBJmDkSUSMoIhkIJYzf8A)

Anonymous code block that takes a list and returns a list. This works by comparing whether each pair of adjacent elements are not equal, than taking the cumulative sum of the list.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
γdƶ˜
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3OaUY9tOz/n/P9pERwGCzMHIEgkZwRBIQSwA)

```
γ       # group adjacent equal digits together
 d      # replace all digits with 1
  ƶ     # multiply each group by its 1-based index
   ˜    # flatten
```

Comment: I keep forgetting that 05ab1e has that `ƶ`... +1

Comment: Here an alternative 4-byter: `ηεγg`

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 33 bytes

```r
function(x)cumsum(c(1,!!diff(x)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP0@jQjO5NLe4NFcjWcNQR1ExJTMtDSimqfk/DShioqMAQeZgZImEjGAIpACoHAA)

Uses the same cumulative sum method as [Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/189943/66252) and others.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 8 bytes

```
Y'wn:wY"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P1K9PM@qPFLp//9oEx0FCDIHI0skZARDIAWxAA)

Explanation:

```
    Y'      % run-length encoding
    w       % swap elements in stack
    n       % number of elements in array / size along each dimension
    :       % range; vector of equally spaced values
    w       % swap elements in stack
    Y"      % replicate elements of array
            % (implicit) convert to string and display
```

Answer (score 2):

## Oracle SQL, 121 bytes

```
select m from t match_recognize(order by i measures match_number()m all rows per match pattern(p+)define p as x=first(x))
```

Test in SQL*PLus.

```
SQL> with t(i,x) as (select rownum,value(v) from table(sys.odcinumberlist(4, 4, 4, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4))v)
  2  select m from t match_recognize(order by i measures match_number()m all rows per match pattern(p+)define p as x=first(x))
  3  /

         M
----------
         1
         1
         1
         2
         2
         3
         3
         3
         3
         4
         4
         4
         5
         5

14 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
▓ª2ªmD?Ä╧╖
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=b2a632a66d443f8ecfb7&i=4,+4,+4,+7,+7,+9,+9,+9,+9,+2,+2,+2,+4,+4&a=1)

The output uses space as a delimiter.  The input follows the precise specifications using commas as separators, and now enclosing braces.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 27 bytes

```perl
s/\d/$i+=$&!=$p;$p=$&;$i/ge
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YPyZFXyVT21ZFTdFWJcdaJQfIslbJ1E9P/f/fREcBgszByBIJGcEQSMG//IKSzPy84v@6BQA)

The command line option `-p` makes perl read the input line from STDIN into the "default variable" `$_`. It then search-replaces all digits in `$_` with the counter `$i`. And `$i` is increased for each digit which is different than the previous digit, which it also is at the first digit so the counter starts at `1`. The previous digit is stored in `$p`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
nƝÄŻ‘
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/v2NzDLUd3P2qY8f//fxMdBQgyByNLJGQEQ1AFAA)

I initially aimed for a 4-byter (the same program but without the `Ż`) but then quickly realized that a **1** had to be prepended every time due to an oversight... Even though there is another 5-byter in Jelly, I'll actually keep this because it uses a different method.

For each pair of neighbouring items of the input list \$L\$, test if \$L_i\ne L_{i+1}, \forall 1\le i<|L|\$ and save these results in a list. Then take the cumulative sum of this list and increment them by **1** to match the chunk indexing system. **TL;DR.** Whenever we encounter different neighbouring items, we increment the chunk index by **1**.

Comment: [I don't think so?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/189932/chunk-enumerate-a-list-of-digits/189955?noredirect=1#comment454606_189932)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>46</s> 43 bytes

```hs
scanl(+)1.map fromEnum.(zipWith(/=)=<<tail)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P822ODkxL0dDW9NQLzexQCGtKD/XNa80V0@jKrMgPLMkQ0PfVtPWxqYkMTNH839uYmaegq1CQVFmXomCikKaQrSJjgIEmYORJRIygiGQgtj/AA)

Anonymous pointfree function that takes a list and returns a list

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>62</strike> 61 bytes

This is one of the few entries I've done where a complete program is shorter than a function submission!

On the first pass, I don't care about the previous value, so I get to rely on the fact that `argv` is a pointer to somewhere and is extremely unlikely to be between [0..9]!

```c
s;main(i,j){for(;~scanf("%d,",&i);j=i)printf("%d ",s+=j!=i);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/7/YOjcxM08jUydLszotv0jDuq44OTEvTUNJNUVHSUctU9M6yzZTs6AoM68ELKigpFOsbZulCBS0rv3/30RHAYLMwcgSCRnBEEjBv@S0nMT04v@65QA)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 12 bytes

```
1+/\@,2~:/\]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVmyrp2CgYKVg8N9QWz/GQceozko/Jva/JpeSnoJ6mq2euoKOQq2VQloxF1dqcka@QpqCCRiaA6ElFBqBIVD0PwA)

Similar to [Adám's APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/189945/75681)

```
      2~:/\]  - pair-wise inequality
1    ,        - prepend 1
    @         - and   
+/\           - find the cumulative sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>13</s> 11 bytes

```
s.e*]hkhbr8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v1gvVSs2Izsjqcji/38THQUIMgcjSyRkBEMgBQA)

```
         r8  # Run-length encode (implicit argument is the input) (-> [[frequency, char], ...]
 .e          # Enumerated map (current element is b, index is k) over rQ8
   *]hk      # [ k+1 ] *
       hb    #           b[0]
s            # Reduce list on + ([a]+[b] = [a,b])
```

-2 bytes thanks to Mr. Xcoder

Comment: `hMsM._+0nVt` for -2 bytes.

Comment: Or if you want to keep your approach, `rQ8` is the same as `r8` and `.n` can be `s` for -2 as well

Comment: Ah nice, the docs didn't mention what functions take an implicit `Q`

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 114 bytes

```scala
s.split(", ").zipWithIndex.scan(s.head,0){(a,b)=>if(a._1==b._1)a else b._1->(a._2+1)}.tail.unzip._2.mkString(", ")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY29CsIwFIX3PEXolGANtgiikIKjg5ODo9w2iY3GGEyEYumzx9QqCB/n/h3u8Q0YiPf6IpuA96Atll2QVni8da5HSEiFFfGbQ3hoe6bfyvvomXdGB5LlOKPspd1Rh3ZnheyYb8ASz1oJIl/QnkBeU15pRYCdCs7rpBSwNF7isZ9X46GcFXRgAbRhT5vepQ27Xae4KSQOyKUpGEsUyZY5nlh9WP9R/hgNGaVoiG8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 75 bytes

```scala
s=>s.scanLeft(("",0))((x,y)=>(y,x._2+(if(x._1!=y)1 else 0))).tail.map(_._2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BCsIwEETv/Yo1pw2GoCKIQgoehd48ipRYU4nENJhFWsRvj7EiCO8wA49hYqOdTt3pahqCBkxPxp8jbEOAZ1E8tIN2U9lIhz3drb8cVTm2naejSlGVUcZG@8q0hMiYmHGO2IuBqxIH0ct6MUXbYg7ziRr4HIyLBrLFJWnr5E0HrLPFU8jz5Dy2yJYCvqxG1n8sfnwEJmNwlpAJYHmv@zzjvHil9AY)

If input and output must be comma separated **String** (and not List) then 102 bytes.

```scala
s=>s.split(", ").scanLeft(("",0))((x,y)=>(y,x._2+(if(x._1!=y)1 else 0))).tail.map(_._2).mkString(", ")
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 62 bytes

```c
f(_,l)int*_;{printf("%d ",l=--l?f(_,l)+(_[l]!=_[l-1]):1);_=l;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3hCoIwFIX/7ylsEGx1R2mW2ZAeRGSEZQibSdqfZM@@7jQh4hwuh3M@uKW4l6VzFVOged30KyWH9omhYnR5DSjoTAh9nvY1U7kuFhleERb8FHKpMi2tQz4wl7phfCA@67zIhhiCycno9MfRbA9YIMbzIXhFqB3EsIcDJHBEpbAd@xh7XK0kFdPQ1e/bAwPffBP@5Vy2r75jlHIPmRkyfxCx7gM)

A function that takes the list and its length as arguments.

---

#### [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 60 bytes

```c
f(_,l)int*_;{_=printf("%*d",--l?f(_,l)+(_[l]!=_[l-1]):2,0);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3hCoIwFIX/7ylsEGx2R2qW2ZAeRETCMoTNJO1Psmdfd5oQcQ6Xwzkf3Ercq8rampWgeNMOfinHMuueGGtG1/6VghDqPO8bVuaqWGV4RVjwUwQBl8Yi6@lL0zI@EpdVXmRjDN7sZHL642ixAwwQ7fgQnCLUDmLYwwESOKJSCKY@xh5XI0nNFPTN@/bAwLffhH85l91r6Bml3EF6gfQfRIz9AA)

Outputs in unary, delimited by `0`s

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 52 bytes

```php
while(''<$d=$argv[++$x])echo$i+=$argv[$x-1]!=$d,' ';
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwMWlr6@QkllckJNYqZCZV1BawpWanJGvkJWfmaehrqCuo5BYVJRYGV@ck5mcqqGSWJRepmOoqamjEOAREO/q72P9vzwjMydVQ13dRiXFFiwfra2tUhGrCTJGJVMbKqZSoWsYq2irkqIDNNT6////JmBoDoSWUGgEhkBRAA)

Input via command line, output to `STDOUT`.

Thx to @Night2 for the pesky `'0' == 0` comparison bugfix!

Comment: @Night2 good catch!  Updated and fixed.  Thx!

Answer (score 1):

## x86-16, 12 bytes

**Unassembled listing:**

```
        NUM_LOOP: 
AC          LODSB                   ; load [SI] into AL, advance SI 
3A C2       CMP  AL, DL             ; is this char same as last? 
74 01       JZ   SAME               ; if so, same index 
43          INC  BX                 ; otherwise increment index 
        SAME: 
92          XCHG AX, DX             ; save current char for next compare 
8A C3       MOV  AL, BL             ; put index value in AL to store
AA          STOSB                   ; store AL into [DI], advance DI
E2 F4       LOOP NUM_LOOP           ; keep looping
```

Input is byte array at `SI`,  length in `CX`.  Output is byte array at `DI`.  Of course, this is if [default I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/) apply now.

**Example:** `SI = 120H`, `DI = 130H`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 38 bytes

```ruby
->a{i=0;a.map{|x,y|p i+=(a==a=x)?0:1}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6xOtPWwDpRLzexoLqmQqeypkAhU9tWI9HWNtG2QtPewMqwtvZ/WnS0iY4CBJmDkSUSMoIhkILY2P8A)

On the first iteration, `a` is equal to the input list, so we always increment the chunk count. On subsequent iterations it's equal to the previous element.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 56 bytes

```julia
l->foldl(l,init=(0,0))do(p,i),c
println(i+=p!=c)
c,i
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcLBCoAgDADQu3/RbaMFRlGn9SPRITRhMVTCoL@34r3zVtn7pwau2i0hqVdQkiiFwZJF9AkyCZIz@ZJYNIK0nBt2aByJOaKvAdaRfgNNn3lDU18)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 37 bytes

```r
function(x,r=rle(x)$l)rep(seq(a=r),r)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP0@jQqfItignVaNCUyVHsyi1QKM4tVAj0bZIU6dI83@aRrKGiY4CBJmDkSUSMoIhkAJNzf8A)

Not as golfy as [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/189994/67312), but an alternative method using `rep`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 65 bytes

```
L=join(1,1-0^{(l[2...]-l)^2})
f(l)=∑_{n=1}^{[1...L.length]}L[n]
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qexml9qznz)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9udie1esxi)

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 45 bytes

```factor
[ 0 f rot [ tuck = rot dup 1 + ? tuck ] map ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY2xCsIwGIT3PsXtgmgRioo4ShcX6VQ6hPiHlqZJTP4MIj57jFG@5e7j4JSQbH3qbu31csBM3pDGInhEGKNSmhDoEclICnCemJ/OT4ZxrKoXdoUms/9TF772nXpsoOAtowdHOeNUyj06bLHC@SeH/OYw5HVtphwg7eJsIEihNdbpAw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 29 bytes

```
1sp&nry[pluy,[',o!]p=!l+spy]p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/9@wuEAtr6gyuiCntFInWl0nXzG2wFYxR7u4oDK24P9/Uy4TIDQHQksoNAJDoCgA)

This one keeps a counter with the chunk number in the backup cell.  That's incremented anytime the current codepoint doesn't match the next one on the list.  The only other trick is the code to conditionally add the `,` delimiter if there's at least one more codepoint on the stack.

```
1sp                           - init the chunk number to 1, pop from stack
   &nr                        - read in list of digits as codepoints
      y[p                 y]p - loop as long as the stack isn't empty
         lu                   - load/print the chunk counter
           y,[   !]p          - if/then, true if there's 2+ digits left
              ',o             - print a comma delimiter
                    =!        - push "1" if the top 2 entries are not equal
                      l+sp    - increment chunk counter is digits differ
```

Answer (score 1):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 7 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

```
+`⊢≠π⊸»
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAgK2DiiqLiiaDPgOKKuMK7CkYg4p+oNCwgNCwgNCwgNywgNywgOSwgOSwgOSwgOSwgMiwgMiwgMiwgNCwgNOKfqQ==)

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 40 bytes

```arturo
$[a][p:10i:0map a'x[if p<>x[i:i+1p:x]i]]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?EBdq4V)

```
$[a][                  ; a function taking an argument a
    p: 10              ; assign 10 to p
    i: 0               ; assign 0 to i
    map a 'x [         ; map over a; assign current element to x
        if p <> x [    ; if p doesn't equal x...
            i: i + 1   ; increment i
            p: x       ; assign x to p
        ]              ; end if
        i              ; map the current element to i
    ]                  ; end map
]                      ; end function
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 38 bytes

Hat-tip to [@pxeger](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218894/15940). [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@F@cWqJgAobmQGgJhUZgCBT9n2draG2nYmidll@kkKlQnVumoKWgkqmmpqGRp62tqWltY2Ojklf7vyhXQev///8A)

```sh
n=1;>$1;for i {mv * $i&&((n++));<<<$n}
```

First we write a file, `>$1`. Then for every argument `$i`:

* attempt to rename that file to `$i`

* if the rename succeeds, increment the chunk number `$n`

* print `$n`

---

##### 50 bytes (old approach)

Compares arguments. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn9P8/W0Lo4tURBxQGIopVjrdPyixQyrVOTM/IVVKJVjGxtVQzt86zytLVj1dSKMzLTSv7XcqUpmIChORBaQqERGIJEaxSKiv//BwA)
  <sub><s>[53 bytes](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn9P8/WUCGxKL0sWkVZ2zDWViWeKy2/SCHTOjU5I19BRUNDxcjWVsXQPs8qT1tbU1NNrTgjM63kfy1XmoIJGJoDoSUUGoEhUPT/fwA)</s></sub>
  <sub><s>[57 bytes](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn9P8/WUMHRVkPFQUElXpMrLb9IIdM6NTkjX0FFQ0PFMdoo1tYWSBnG2udZ5Wlra2qqqRVnZKaVKDj@r@VKUzABQ3MgtIRCIzAEiv7/DwA)</s></sub>

```pascal
n=1;set $@ $@[#];for i;echo $[$2==$1?n:n++]&&shift
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ƒ€ġḷ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDNiU5MiVFMiU4MiVBQyVDNCVBMSVFMSVCOCVCNyZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PTQlMkMlMjA0JTJDJTIwNCUyQyUyMDclMkMlMjA3JTJDJTIwOSUyQyUyMDklMkMlMjA5JTJDJTIwOSUyQyUyMDIlMkMlMjAyJTJDJTIwMiUyQyUyMDQlMkMlMjA0JmZsYWdzPWU=)

##### Explanation

```python
ƒ€ġḷ  # Implicit input
ƒ     # Prefixes
 €    # To each:
  ġ   #  Group consecutive
   ḷ  # Length of each
      # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 4 bytes

```
pNĉ#
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHHBgqWlJWm6FksL_I50Ki8pTkouhoosuKkVbaKjAEHmYGSJhIxgCKQgFqIFAA)

```
pNĉ#
pN      Nonempty prefix
  ĉ     Chunks of identical characters
   #    Length
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0, 9 bytes

```
£T±A¦(A=X
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=o1SxQaYoQT1Y&input=WzQsIDQsIDQsIDcsIDcsIDksIDksIDksIDksIDIsIDIsIDIsIDQsIDRd)

Answer (score 0):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 23 bytes

```
D,f,@*,BGd€bL$bLRz€¦XBF
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99FJ03HQUvHyT3lUdOaJB@VJJ@gKiDr0LIIJ7f/Kml29lz@//9HmyiAoDkQWkKhERgCRWMB)

### How it works

```
D,f,@*,     - Define a function, f, that takes one argument:  [7 7 5 5 5 1]
       BG   - Group neighbouring elements together:           [[[7 7] [5 5 5] [1]]]          
       d    - Duplicate:                                      [[[7 7] [5 5 5] [1]] [[7 7] [5 5 5] [1]]]
       €bL  - Get the length of each:                         [[[7 7] [5 5 5] [1]] [2 3 1]]
       $bLR - Length, then range of length:                   [[2 3 1] [1 2 3]]
       z    - Zip together:                                   [[2 1] [3 2] [1 3]]
       €¦X  - Reduce each by repetition:                      [[1 1] [2 2 2] [3]]
       BF   - Flatten:                                        [1 1 2 2 2 3]
            - Due to the * in the function definition,
                 return the whole stack:                      [1 1 2 2 2 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
ä¦Ug)åÄ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=5KZVZynlxA&input=WzQsIDQsIDQsIDcsIDcsIDksIDksIDksIDksIDIsIDIsIDIsIDQsIDRd)

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 34 bytes

```
\b\d+\b(?<=(\b(\3|(\d+))\D*)*)
$#3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/JikmRTsmScPexlYDSMUY12gABTQ1Y1y0NLU0uVSUjf//N9FRgCBzMLJEQkYwBFIAAA) Explanation:

```
\b\d+\b
```

Match each number in turn.

```
(?<=(...)*)
```

Start looking backwards for as many matches as possible. (The next entries will be in right-to-left order as that's how lookbehind works.)

```
\D*
```

Skip the separators.

```
(\3|(\d+))
```

Try to match the same number as last time, but failing that, just match any number, but remember that we had to match a new number.

```
\b
```

Ensure the whole number is matched.

```
$#3
```

Count the number of new numbers.

Answer (score 0):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 28 bytes

```
0wi.hn$@.?-..3&$!h0;./ O \K
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/9@gPFMvI0/FQc9eV0/PWE1FMcPAWk9fwV8hxpvr/38TExNzc0sgMDIyMjExNDI2MTUzt7A0AAA)

Takes the input as a string with no separators, outputs a string separated by new line

### Explanations

```
0                             Initialise the counter at 0 on the stack
 wi.hn$@                  K   Main loop, while there are characters to read on the input
        .?-    $   ;          If the number read is the same as the number on the tape, discard it
           ..3& !h0           Otherwise, store the new number on the tape and increment the counter
                    ./ O \    Print the counter and a new line
```